# Hidden SQL Columns & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2016, ef-database-first, temporal-tables

We have a few azure sql tables where we created 'temporal tables' (history) on. In order to create these tables we added 2 'HIDDEN' columns (ValidTo & ValidFrom) to the main table.

The issue comes when we update our EF model (db first) the hidden columns come into the auto-generated model and our existing code breaks.

Is there some way we can set something to ignore these columns from being auto-generated into our model?

Comment: Might it not be better to split this data into another table with a 1:1 primary key mapping to the "main table"?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your issue. Why does it break existing code? It only adds two properties doesn't it? You can delete the properties in the EDMX designer and they won't return after update.

Comment: @gert arnold - they come back after removing properties & regenerate the model.

Comment: You should give more details of your process. This doesn't sound like database-first.

Comment: @GertArnold - We open the EDMX >  Right click > Update Model from DB. On saving the EDMX file, the classes are regenerated. I am about to put a little more clarifying context...

Comment: The problem is when these columns (despite being added as HIDDEN ) get into the EF model, they break saving the enties with error "Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table 'xxx'. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column, or insert a DEFAULT into GENERATED ALWAYS column."

People suggest registering an IDbCommandTreeInterceptor so that these columns are'nt listed on insert/update. 

Another way is to remove these columns from EDMX but this is not an option for people like me who prefer to regen edmx and lazy to make manual changes:)